# How to sign out of Google Play Games?

Tags: applications, google-play-games

I'm developing an app with Google Play Games' achievement system, but I want to test the flow when a user is not signed into Google Play Games.

How can I sign out of Google Play Games to test this flow?

Comment: I think you must remove your account from the device.

Comment: Google uses a single-sign-on system for their apps, so you are logged in in every app or nowhere. Thus you have to completely remove your Google account in Android settings.

Answer (score 3):

I found how to sign out per-game. It seems to test that workflow.

1. Open the *Play Games* app
2. Go to ⋮ (menu) > Settings > (Your Data heading) > Change account for games
3. Find your game in the list
4. Tap *Change* to get options:

   - Select an account (default)
   - Ask each time
   - Sign out